# Do setting selected value of a select box trigger change event of the select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting the selected value of a select list as below

```
$("#typeFilter").val("0");
```

My question is do making this, triggers `$("#typeFilter").change` event?

Comment: How about trying that out yourself and let us know too ?

Comment: Have you even tried to check if it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it won't trigger the change event if you want to trigger the event after setting the value use `trigger`. Change event is triggered only if it is an interaction from device not with javascript.

```
$("#typeFilter").val("0");
$("#typeFilter").trigger('change');
```

### [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j7kHX/)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't! Unless the value is changed by user interaction, change event would not be triggered.

You can try it out yourself. Select any textbox's id. Lets say the id is "inputEmail". Try the following code:

```
$("#inputEmail").change(function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

Then try the following line of code:

```
$("#inputEmail").val("abc");
```

Notice that the alert message did not appear.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't trigger it as it can bee seen in this [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/nhmJE/). You will need to trigger it manually after setting the value:

```
$("#typeFilter").change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nopes. It doesn't change. This is the code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#test").val("3");
    }, 1000);
    $("#test").change(function(){
        alert("Changed!");
    });
});
```

So, if you would like to trigger the change, you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").val("3").trigger("change");
    $("#test").change(function(){
        alert("Changed!");
    });
});
```

#### Fiddles:
http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/kLJuS/
http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/kLJuS/1/